# How to extract sub string from a String for the entire range of string and put them in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, string, nsstring

I have string

`NSString *str = @"M 2 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3M 1 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"`

I want to an array of substrings like `["2 2","5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3","1 2","5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"]`

I want to map it with the type in a dictionary like
`["M":"2 2", "C":"5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"]`

I found it is possible to get the substring using the range property

```
NSString *str = @"M 2 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3M 1 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"

NSRange r1 = [str rangeOfString:@"M"];
NSRange r2 = [str rangeOfString:@"C"];
NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
NSString *sub = [s substringWithRange:rSub];
```

But the letter M and C are in any random order. How can I solve this for the entire length of string and put it into an array ?

Comment: Your string is dynamic? i mean can be any Letter or must be M and C?

Comment: what should be the exactly result for "M 2 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3M 1 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3" in terms of "map it with the type in a dictionary"? Because following string contains two 'M' and there can be only one 'M' in the dictionary as key.

Comment: Wait... you say `I want to an array of substrings like ["2 2","5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3","1 2","5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"` and `I want to map it with the type in a dictionary like "["M":"2 2", "C":"5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"]`. How do the array and the dictionary relate? As Arun pointed out, you have the key "M" in your sample data twice, but a dictionary key is unique.

Comment: You need to do a better job of defining your problem. It looks like you are treating the characters "M" and "C" as delimiters for dividing up your string, and also as keys in your output dictionary. You need to explain your goal more clearly. Also, in your sample data you have all single characters separated by spaces except one instance of "3M". Is that valid data, or should there be a space between the "3" and the "M"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

```
NSString *str = @"M 2 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3M 1 2 C 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([A-Z])([\\d\\s]*)" options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSString *letter = [str substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];
    NSString *numbers = [str substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];
    NSMutableArray *subArray = dict[letter]?dict[letter]:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [subArray addObject:numbers];
    [dict setObject:subArray forKey:letter];
}];

NSLog(@"Dict: %@", dict);
```

Output:

```
$>Dict: {
    C =     (
        " 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3",
        " 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"
    );
    M =     (
        " 2 2 ",
        " 1 2 "
    );
}
```

How it works:
We use a RegularExpression to find groups of "Letter + anyamountof(any space + any Number)".
We use extra parenthesis in the pattern to define "groups".
We enumerate the matches, and since we defined groups earliers, we can use `rangeAtIndex:` of the `NSTextCheckingResult` found to get easily the letter, and the numbers.
Then we store it into an `NSDictionary`
.

What can be replaced according to your needs

Removing space before/after the number list:

```
NSString *numbers = [[str substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Which gives:

```
$>Dict: {
    C =     (
        "5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3",
        "5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3"
    );
    M =     (
        "2 2",
        "1 2"
    );
}
```

Or removing all spaces:

```
NSString *numbers = [[str substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Which gives:

```
$>Dict: {
    C =     (
        56789123,
        56789123
    );
    M =     (
        22,
        12
    );
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with theses info, because that wasn't clear at all. And the result CAN'T BE A DICTIONARY. Dict have no order, and can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: I had to work with it a little, the RE is `@"([A-Z])([\[0-9][.]\\s]*)"` so that it captures the floating point values. I made temp dictionary and inserted each dictionary into an array. Thanks for the input. Its working now.